# Stopping aplaymidi leaves stuck notes

Tags: linux, usb, midi

I'm using the `aplaymidi` command to run a hardware device over a USB MIDI adaptor.  For the most part it works fine, but stopping playback with <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> leaves stuck notes.  So far, the only way I've been able to release the stuck notes is to play a MIDI file of a 127 note chromatic scale.  This is slow, and listening to the scale is undesirable.

Is there simply a way to output every `"note off"` command when cancelling a file playback?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `aplaymidi` into a script that checks the exit status to detect Ctrl+C:

```
#!/bin/bash
aplaymidi "$*"
test $? == 130 && aplaymidi .../AllNotesOff.mid
```

The "all notes off" message is controller 123; just send it on all channels at the same time.

Alternatively, use `amidi` to send a reset message:

```
... && amidi -p hw:X -S F07E7F0901F7
```

where `X` is the card number; see `amidi -l` for a list of ports.

Comment: Where would I find or how would I make a MIDI file which sends this command?

Comment: Any sequencer would be able to create such a file.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a sequencer which can do this.  Also, could you explain the raw hex MIDI commands?  I can't find good documentation on what `0xF0` is other than "system exclusive".

Comment: P. 52 of the [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification).